# Why does Castle ActiveRecord FindAllByProperty method Not using Cache

Tags: c#, caching, nhibernate, activerecord, castle-activerecord

I have the following class;

```
[ActiveRecord(Lazy = true)]
[DataContract]
public class Room : ActiveRecordBase<Room>
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    [DataMember]
    public virtual Int64 RoomId { get; protected set; }

    [Property]
    [DataMember]
    public virtual Int64 HotelId { get; set; }

    [Property]
    [DataMember]
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }

    [Property]
    [DataMember]
    public virtual string Description { get; set; }

    public static Room[] FindByHotelId(Int64 HotelId)
    {
        using (new SessionScope())
        {    
            return (Room[])Room.FindAllByProperty(typeof(Room), "HotelId", HotelId);
        }
    }
}
```

Although I'm using

> new SessionScope()

When calling FindAllByProperty(), the database is always queried to get the data, rather than return the data from the cache.

If I call

> Room.Find(1);

The response is given from the cache, with no query being made to the database.

Why is this happening, are there any Castle ActiveRecord experts that can help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm no expert at Castle ActiveRecord but I guess that doesn't matter..

NHibernate uses a 1st level cache/identity map. When, you within a session, fetches the same object multiple times you are guaranteed to get the same instance back. In your case, this means that this assert should pass...

```
Assert.AreSame(
 Room.FindAllByProperty(typeof(Room), "HotelId", HotelId).First(),
 Room.FindAllByProperty(typeof(Room), "HotelId", HotelId).First())
```

However, the db query itself will be called everytime you make the call. This is true for any query except session.Get and session.Find (what these are called in Castle ActiveRecord I don't know).

If you want to start the queries themself you need to enable 2nd level caching. There is plenty of information about this on the [internet](https://www.google.com/search?q=2nd%20level%20caching%20nhibernate&oq=2nd%20level%20caching%20nhibernate).

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  But what I don't understand is if I call Room.Find(1) I can't see the db being queried (in the db log files), but can see the data being returned correctly in my app.

Comment: That's probably because x.Find(1) in Castle ActiveRecord means session.Get or session.Find. Those nhib methods uses 1st level cache directly.